# Question about fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let be $f(x)=\displaystyle \int_x^{2x} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt$

Why 
$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{\sin{2x}}x -\frac{\sin{x}}x$ and not $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{\sin{2x}}{2x} -\frac{\sin{x}}x$?

Think it's quite stupid but I don't understand which theorem is applied. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$G(x)=\int_\alpha^x g(t)dt$$
so
$$G'(x)=g(x)$$

and let 
$$f(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(t)dt=G(b(x))-G(a(x))=G\circ b(x)-G\circ a(x)$$
then by the chain rule
$$f'(x)=G'(b(x))\times  b'(x)-G'(a(x))\times  a'(x)=g(b(x))\times  b'(x)-g(a(x))\times  a'(x)$$
In your example
$$g(t)=\frac{\sin t}t\quad;\quad a(x)=x\quad;\quad b(x)=2x$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\int_a^x{g(t)dt}$$ Then you know that $$f'(x)=g(x)$$ By the chain rule, we would get that $$\frac{d}{dx}f(2x)=\frac{d}{dx}(2x)\cdot f'(2x)=2g(2x)$$ Do you see why the 2 was cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's easier to write it as $f(x)=\displaystyle \int_0^{2x} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt-\displaystyle \int_0^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt$, so that we have a constant as the lower limit.  (You could replace $0$ with any other number if you want.)  Now the fundamental theorem of calculus states that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{du}\int_a^{u} g(t) \,dt = g(u)$.  So if we let $u=2x$, then $\displaystyle \frac{d}{du}\int_0^{u} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt=\frac{\sin(u)}u=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}$.  But we're not interested in the derivative with respect to $u$, we're interested in the derivative with respect to $x$, so we have to apply the chain rule: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{u} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt=\frac{d}{du} \left( \int_0^{u} \frac{\sin(t)}t \,dt \right)\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}(2)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$.